# What is difference between type=number and type=text in JavaScript regex?

Tags: javascript, regex, types, filtering, phone-number

Script have to count 3 chars and filtering anything what isn't a digit.
After any 3 digits, script puts :" - ";
Then prevent from add more than 9 digit.

Anything worked fine, while I use "type=text" in input.
When I using "type=number" (which is important to my new task), script isn't works, well `(replace(/(.{3})/g,'$1 - ')`, puts last 3 chars in input [as I guess]).

My question is:

Is existed difference between both types in regex perspective?

Maybe "type=number" parseing string to int? (but as I know, pure (without JS) "type=number" won't filtering anything in real time).

Ps. Sorry for terrible language.

Now Code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var selection = document.querySelector('.correct_phone input[name=phone]');
  //selection.setAttribute('type','number');
  selection.addEventListener('input', function(e) {
    selection.addEventListener('keydown', function(b) {

      if (b.keyCode != 8 && b.keyCode != 46 && b.keyCode != 37 && b.keyCode != 39 && b.keyCode != 16 && b.keyCode != 17 && b.keyCode != 18) {
        if (e.target.value.length < 14 && e.target.value.length > 0) {
          $(selection).parent('.correct_phone').find('.error_list.not_digit').remove();
          //e.target.value = e.target.value.replace(/[^\dA-Z]/g, '').replace(/(.{3})/g, '$1 ').trim(); /^\d+$/
          e.target.value = e.target.value.replace(/[^\d]/g, '').replace(/(.{3})/g, '$1 - ').trim();
        } else if (e.target.value.length > 14) {
          $(selection).parent('.correct_phone').find('.error_list.not_digit').remove();
          e.target.value = e.target.value.substring(0, e.target.value.length - 1);
          $(selection).parent('.correct_phone').css('border-color', 'red').find('label').before("<ul style='margin-bottom:0px;' class='error_list not_digit'><li style=' font-size:1.1em;'>Nuber shuld contains only 9 digits</li></ul>");
          $(selection).parent('.correct_phone').find('ul.error_list.not_digit').animate({
            opacity: 0
          }, 3000, function() {
            $(this).remove();
          });
        }
      } else
        $(selection).parent('.correct_phone').find('.error_list.not_digit').remove();
    });
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="fieldset semi correct_phone">
  <label class="input-name">Phone:</label>
  <input type="text" name="phone" value="" />


</div>
```

Comment: How does "type=number" not filter realtime?

Comment: There's no difference in `value`, both are type of string, when you read a value in JS.

Comment: Why you have nested event attachments? There's `addEventListener('keydown',..)` in `oninput` handler. That is guaranteed to cause you troubles. Btw. the difference is, that if an input type of number contains a non-numeric value, the value is read as an empty string in handlers like `oninput` or `onchange`. Also, looks like `onchange` would fire only once in this case.

Comment: Thats the point.
Soo .. what could I do with this problem?
I really need "type=number", and rest of script is also important to me (particularly filtering, as is described in first post).

Comment: I nesting events because I have to count string length ( in real time, not by enter return), and also I have problem with ctrl shift and alse, special keys.

Comment: Now I know what to ask.
How to chack type="nuber" to read value as type=text.

:) any ideas ?

Comment: You can't, if user enters a non-numeric value, events are not fired, or passing you malinformation. You'll never get a chance to read the real value entered to input. That's how `type="number"` works, it validates the value automatically, in a way.

Comment: Ok I read something about inputs property, and I have one more question.
Why willValidate DOM property is read only ,and I can't edit this value.
If is some way to change this value, please tell me how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [W3 input type="number" specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#number-state-(type=number)), the `type="number"` is reserved for *floating-point numbers*.

Specifically the following line describes the bug you're encountering:

> **The value sanitization algorithm is as follows**: If the value of the element is not a valid floating-point number, then set it to the empty string instead.

So in your code you're setting the value of the input to something that is not a floating-point number:

```
e.target.value = e.target.value.replace(/[^\d]/g, '').replace(/(.{3})/g, '$1 - ').trim();
```

As that `-` character is considered as a *bad input*, the browser follows the specification and sets the value to an empty string.

To fix this, you should use the `type="tel"`, which accepts any valid telephone number as an input:

```
<input type="tel" name="phone" value="" />
```

This sets the modern mobile browsers to show numeric keyboard layout (like the `type="number"`.